# SQL:How to extract a substring between a specific pattern?

Tags: sql-server, string, ssms

I have a string as follows in Microsoft SQL server management studio

A,5000;B,**3000**;LC,3000

I need to extract the value preceeding ';LC' and after the 2nd last comma of the string.

In the above example, my substring should read 3000 (this is desired result).

I have identified PATINDEX function as part of the solution, but cannot figure out how to identify the 2nd last comma of a string.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? regex feature are very different between the various products

Comment: which sql database is this(Oracle/Sql server/MySql...)?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not elegant and long solution is to use PATHINDEX, REVERSE and SUBSTRING functions:

```
SELECT 
    REVERSE(
        SUBSTRING(
            REVERSE(SUBSTRING([column],0,PATINDEX('%;LC%',[column]))),
            0,
            PATINDEX('%,%',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([column],0,PATINDEX('%;LC%',[column])))))
    )
    from [table]
```

Comment: thank you very much!!
this solution seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross apply:

```
select substring(myColumn, p4.Pos + 1, P2.Pos - p4.Pos - 1) Before2nd
from myTable
  cross apply (select (charindex(';', myColumn))) as P1(Pos)
  cross apply (select (charindex(';', myColumn, P1.Pos+1))) as P2(Pos)
  cross apply (select (charindex(',', myColumn))) as P3(Pos)
  cross apply (select (charindex(',', myColumn, P3.Pos+1))) as P4(Pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use "/XMLRoot/RowData" Like below Example:

DECLARE @StringList NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @StringList  ='A,5000;B,3000;LC,3000'
   --INSERT INTO TABLEName (col)
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS OutPutList FROM ( SELECT CAST('' + REPLACE(@StringList,',','') + '' AS XML) AS t
       )tbl CROSS APPLY t.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)

Answer (score 0):

To find the 2nd last comma of a string, you can use `REVERSE()` function.

Try below solution:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)='A,5000;B,3000;LC,3000'

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@String),CHARINDEX(';',REVERSE(@String))+1,CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(@String),CHARINDEX(';',REVERSE(@String)))-CHARINDEX(';',REVERSE(@String))-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Declare @var varchar(30)
   set @var='A,5000;B,3000;LC,3000'
   Select Right(LefT(@var,CHARINDEX(';LC',@var)-1),
          CHARINDEX(',',Reverse(LefT(@var,CHARINDEX(';LC',@var)-1)))-1)
```